# How to remove everything that occurs after the last occurrence of a character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For example, I have a string

"A - B - C asdas K - A,B,C"

Let the character be "-"

I want to save everything before the last occurrence of "-" so "A - B - C asdas K " should be saved.

I have tried this:

```
str = str.split(":").pop();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and any specific error/issue you may have encountered. Please keep in mind that SO is not a code-writing service..

Comment: Can you show some code that yout tried ?

Comment: `lastIndexOf` <-- this should help. `const someText = "A - B - C asdas K - A,B,C"; console.log(someText.slice(0, someText.lastIndexOf('-')));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var str = "A - B - C asdas K - A,B,C";
console.log(str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("-")));
```

Firstly, you get the last index of the char that interest you: '-', then you are using substring which get 0-X string.